# Given $(N,N)$ martix that represents "winning" probabilities, how to rank the competitors

Tags: probability, game-theory

Assume a competition with $N$ "players". We represent all "games" using matrix $P$ of shape $(N, N)$, where the entry $P[i,j]$ is the probability of player $i$ winning player $j$.

I would like to **rank** players according to that matrix.

One heuristic could be "binarize the probabilities to $1$ if $p_{i,j}>0.5$ and $0$ otherwise", then count the number of wins, and sort by that number. This is, however, pretty coarse, because we do not account for the actual probability. Another option is to sum the probabilities, but then we might end with $0.99+0.01+0.01 < 0.35+0.35+0.35$.
I was thinking about something like Page Rank.

Wondering if there is a "canonical" problem that my setting falls into, and what are the possible directions.

Comment: I would suggest ranking them according to their expected number of wins $\sum_{j=1}^Np_{ij}$

Comment: Adding the probabilities corresponds to letting them play a tournament with each pair meeting (in the limit) infinitely many times and the usual 1 point for the winner. Sounds fair.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You could also try to estimate the ELOs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) of each player. Given the ELOs of the two players, there is a formula that gives you the winning probability for each player. Notice however that ELOs assume "transitivity": if player A is favourite against B and B is favourite against C, A is favourite against C. Can't know it this happens in your matrix.

Comment: Over $K$ games between $i$ and $j$ player $i$ will, on expectation, win $p_{ij}K$ games. So if all pairs play $K$ games the expected number of wins for player $i$ is $K\sum_{j\neq i} p_{ij}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the comments answer the question pretty well, but I'm just going to elaborate a bit more.

Probably the most reasonable (and simplest) way of ranking the competitors is by  their expected number of wins in a tournament where everyone plays each other once. This is also the same as ranking them based on a 'limiting' leaderboard, where the tournament carries on indefinitely with everyone playing each other infinitely often, but with each match occurring in equal proportions.

This boils down to calculating $\sum_{j=1}^Np_{ij}$ for each player $j$, and ranking in order of size.

But what happens when two players have an equal expected number of wins? The best we can do for this is to then compare the players based on their winning probabilities against each other. If these are equal, we can reasonably give them the same rank. However, depending on what characteristics you want your tournament to favour, you could compare them using different metrics such as their minimum win probability across all their opponents.